# CXF WebClient overrides HTTP Content-Type

Tags: http-headers, client, cxf

I'm trying to act as a proxy to a third party webservice, and need to transform a REST request.  One issue that I have is that the Content-Type header seems to get overridden no matter what I do.  The code is actually very simple (context is an @Context MessageContext
variable):

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(url)
    .header("real-header-removed", "auth-string-removed")           
    //.header("Content-Type", context.getHttpHeaders().getMediaType().toString());
    .type(context.getHttpHeaders().getMediaType());

Response resp = client.get();
return (InputStream)resp.getEntity();
```

Neither the .header nor the .type worked.  The tcpmon output of the request is:

```
Content-Type: */*
real-header-removed: auth-string-removed
Accept: application/xml
User-Agent: Apache CXF 2.3.5
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
```

How do I avoid the Content-Type override (or rather, why is it
happening?)

Comment: Ok, figured it out.  I needed to use client.invoke("GET", "");  For those that wonder why I need to do this, I'm actually, not looking to set a Content-Type on a GET, I just don't want the */* override.  The third party service that I'm using calculates a sig using the Content-Type header, if set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use client.invoke("GET", "");